# what all will happen at the machine level when I run a java program file using the "java file_name" command?

Tags: java

I would like to know what happens internally at the machine level when I try to run a java compiled file  using the command **"java class_name**" If you know how the classes loaded into JVM will start executing with the help of Program Counter (PC) or any other pointers to the memory please explain it.
Like,
what loadClass() will do and its internal calls to findClass() and other methods. In that detail I am expecting the answer to be.

Answer (score 1):

From `Java` doc

> The java command starts a Java application. It does this by starting
>   a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and calling
>   that class's main method.

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html).

Comment: ya that I know but my concern is what all classes will be triggered and what instances will be created in the course of running the java program.